# One of my Flows is missing!

Tags: flow

I've inherited a number of Flows which I can see in Team Flows. However one of the Flows failed and I can't track it down. I click on the 'See your flows' drop down in the library but it just takes me to Team Flows and leaves me none the wiser.

The Flow is now working but I want to take a look at it so I can prevent it failing again. How could I track it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably that flow wasn't shared with you so you cannot see its definition. You need to contact your tenant admins (or the previous owner of the flow) so they can assign ownership to you.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it was something like that. I'll put the request in.